# Scala recursive function directly return the input list

Tags: scala

The Scala definition f:

```
def f[X](xs:List[X]):List[X]={
  xs match{
  case Nil=>xs
  case y::ys=>y::f(ys)
  }
}
```

Consider the expression:

### `f(List(1,2))`

### And It returns a List(1,2)

I am curious that why the answer is not List(1,2,1,2) or List(1,2,List(1,2))

Since,

```
Step1.(when we input the List(1,2))
it will match the "case y::ys=>y::f(ys)"
So it becomes "case 1::2=>1::f(2)"
Continue to recursive.
```

```
Step2,
it also match the "case y::ys=>y::f(ys)"
So it becomes "case 2::Nil=>2::f(Nil)"
Continue to recursive.
```

```
Step3,
it will match  "case Nil=>xs"
So it becomes "case Nil=>List(1,2)"
And because previous steps 1 and 2 are recursive.
when we meet the base case it should become
"1::2::List(1,2)"
```

But it looks just directly returns the xs(List(1,2)) for the final answer.
Am I misunderstood about scala recursive function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake in your step 3.

Prior to Step 3, your call is

```
f(xs=Nil)
```

so it matches Nil and since xs is also nil it returns it. Meaning it actually becomes

```
case Nil => Nil
```

Recursion doesn't keep the original parameters.

So it becomes

```
> 1 :: 2 :: Nil 
> 1 :: List(2)
> List(1,2)
```

Comment: Thank you!
The point you give "Recursion doesn't keep the original parameters" is really helpful.